# Tuning a complex query

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

Working on report extract and complex query is taking 3 hours. Need suggestions for tuning

there is a main table which contains 3M records and the iteration is taking long time due to multiple joins

Tables:

- Employee
- Department
- Address
- Paystubs
- Tax

Employee table has 3M records and when I run the following query it is taking around 3hours to get the data.
Need to get the data of those employees alone where there is change in their data from yesterday to today

```
select 
    emp.employee_id || '|' || emp.int_acct_id || '|' || dpt.department_desc
    || '|' || dpt.start_date || '|' || dpt.end_date
    || '|' || dpt.productivity_percent || '|' || addr.street_addr 
    || '|' || addr.apt || '|' || addr.city  || '|' || addr.state
    || '|' || addr.country || '|' || addr.zip || '|' || pay_for_year 
    || '|' || total_paid || '|' || pay_for_current_year || '|' || w2_issue_flg
from employee emp
inner join (
  select int_acct_id from (
    select int_acct_id from employee 
    where last_updated_time between '03-nov-19' and '04-nov-19'
    union
    select int_acct_id from department 
    where last_updated_time between '03-nov-19' and '04-nov-19'
  ) dual
) a1 on emp.int_acct_id = a1.int_acct_id
left outer join (
  select department_desc, start_date, end_date, int_acct_id, 
    productivity_percent from department
) dpt on emp.int_acct_id = dpt.int_acct_id
left outer join (
  select addr_acct_id, employee_id, street_addr, apt, city, state, country, zip
  from address
) addr on emp.employee_id = addr.employee_id
left outer join (
  select a.pay_for_year, a.four_not_one as total_paid, 
    b.total_pay as pay_for_curren_year, a.int_acct_id from tax a, (
      select sum(total_pay) as total_pay, int_acct_id 
      from paystubs  where pay_year = (select cur_year from year_dat) 
      group by int_acct_id
    ) b
  where a.int_acct_id = b.int_acct_id(+)
) on a.int_acct_id = emp.int_acct_id
```

Is there any other way or method we could use to first filter out the modified records in timestamp and then check for other values. (Cursor is not an option here for me)
the data is to load from Oracle DB to AIX server and hence it is taking time.
Also Hints are not helping, i tried Leading / ordered both and no luck.

Comment: Step #1 is to run an explain plan and look at that.

Comment: Yes - start by getting the explain plan and seeing where the issue is. For example an explain plan will tell is if we need an index on `LAST_UPDATED_TIME`. It would also help if you just told us what the indexes are.

Comment: Can you edit your question and tell us how many records are in each table and what the PK is and any indexes of note in the tables. That is _far_ more valuable than a list of columns in a table.

Comment: ... in fact I just removed a bunch of extraneous info and now your question actually looks approachable.

Comment: 1) The `dual` subquery is in excess. Remove it.

Comment: 2) The `left outer join` against `department` does not need a `SELECT`. Remove it.

Comment: 3) The left outer join against `address` does not need a SELECT. Remove it.

Comment: 4) Please use modern JOIN syntax -- instead of (+) -- available since SQL-92.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention indexes.
1) INT_ACCT_ID on all and Employee_id in Address table.
2) Primary key is also INT_ACCT_ID 
3) I created Index on LAST_UPDATED_TIME but it din't work much for the DUAL query. 
4) Why I used DUAL is, I need to only pick those records where there is a change in the values. For those employees whose data got changed I need to run this report.
5) I read online that SELECT will yield faster results than simply using LEFT OUTER JOIN. (Is it wrong)?

Comment: address table would have more than 3M records, PAYSTUBS will have more than 3M records

Comment: Please edit the question and add this info. Also get the explain plan and post that

Comment: The issue is identified at IO load. So while extracting the data from multiple tables and writing it on a unix server, the network load is what making the file write slow. I created two views and wrote a join query on views for required data, now the time came down to 2 minutes :) thanks everyone